# Utilizing Horizontal Scroll View with a listview below

Tags: android

I am attempting to create a tab based activity with seven tabs.  Tabhost won't allow me to scroll multiple tabs so i created a HorizontalScrollView containing seven buttons at the top of the page.

I am now stuck trying to figure out the best method to allow for incorporating the different listview activities i need to display depending on which button is pressed.

I'm just looking for a push in the right direction.  I have researched utilizing activityGroups but I can't seem to figure out how to get that to display under the hroizontal listview.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all tabs are just lists then why can't you just changes the adapter instead of changing the view.

Other choice is to have 7 layout and hide them all. I think you can use FrameLayout to track all of them.

Answer (score 0):

> I am attempting to create a tab based
>   activity with seven tabs.

You probably shouldn't do this. Instead of using so many tabs check out using a dashboard instead

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html